# Data disappears when url route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating web app with tabletop.js, handlebars.js, and angular.js

So the data is fetching from google spreadsheet and using angular for routing
but when after route to another page and come back data disappears

[Here's a Plunker of it](http://plnkr.co/HcGYGJ77gysA1JxpD1Gi)

Can someone give a solution please, i've tried searching but no luck yet :/

Tabletop controllers

> ```
>   var public_spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AkLy8qCw6J5EdGlmeFZEVVVZZ3ZUSEhYcjhEdEZKelE&output=html';
>
>   $(document).ready( function() {
>     Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
>                      callback: showInfo,
>                      parseNumbers: true } );
>   });
>
>   function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
>     var source   = $("#cat-template").html();
>     var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
>
>     $.each( tabletop.sheets("Cats").all(), function(i, cat) {
>       var html = template(cat);
>       $("#content").append(html);
>     });
>   }
> ```

And these are angular scripts

```
    var routeApp = angular.module('routeApp', []);

    routeApp.filter('range', function() {
        return function(input, total) {
            total = parseInt(total);
            for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
                input.push(i);
            }
            return input;
        };
    });

    routeApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.
            when('/home', { controller: HomeCtrl, templateUrl: 'partials/home.html' }).
            when('/movie/:id', { controller: BlogDetailCtrl, templateUrl: 'partials/movieDetail.html' }).
            when('/product', { controller: ProductCtrl, templateUrl: 'partials/product.html' }).                
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

    });

    function MainCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.navs = [
            { text: 'Products', href: '#/product' },                
        ];

    }

    function HomeCtrl($scope) {         
        console.log($scope);            
    }

    function BlogDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

        $scope.youAreClick = function(what) {
            alert('You are click on ' + what);
        }
    }

    function ProductCtrl($scope) {          
        $scope.items = [
            { grid: 3.5, filename: '360x270' },
            { grid: 3.5, filename: '260x120' },
            { grid: 3, filename: '160x120' },
            { grid: 3, filename: '260x120' },
            { grid: 3, filename: '260x120' } 
        ];          
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide your controller code?

Comment: @BKM Topic updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are created/destroyed on the fly each time your route changes. Data stored in them is not persistent.

One way of overcoming this is to use a [Service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services).

As stated in the documentation: *"Lastly, it is important to realize that all Angular services are application singletons."*

Comment: Sergiu is right - use a service to store your data and inject it in the controllers you need it.

Comment: seems like this works for now, but getting some issues with cache ( not sure coz of this or not )

Comment: Are you using Resource? If so then check out http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$cacheFactory

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Angular-Multi-View](https://github.com/vincentdieltiens/Angular-Multi-View), specifically the `persist()` method. It lets you persist a view's scope across routing changes.